# Is this ctor / use of ctor correct?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, member

```
    SingleMonitorInfo::SingleMonitorInfo(MONITORINFOEX* lpMONITORINFOEX)
    :rcMonitorArea(lpMONITORINFOEX->rcMonitor),
    rcWorkArea(lpMONITORINFOEX->rcWork),
    dwStatusFlags(lpMONITORINFOEX->dwFlags),
    szDeviceName({ '\0' }),
    szMonitorName({ '\0' }),
    szMonitorDescription({ '\0' }),
    lpPixelArray(NULL)
{
    wcscpy_s(SingleMonitorInfo::szDeviceName, 33, lpMONITORINFOEX->szDevice);
    SingleMonitorInfo::setStringMonitorNameAndDescription(lpMONITORINFOEX->szDevice);
}
```

I am rewriting my program using member initialisation lists, I hope the code above is correct, although this is the first time I've used member initialisation lists.

I realised that later on, in a parent of this class: I was creating another copy, of a copy to create (Instantiate I think) the list. When all I think I needed was:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lpMonitorList->iMaximumSize; i++)
    {
        smiMonitorList[i] = SingleMonitorInfo(&lpMonitorList->infoArray[i]);
    }
```

It seems too simple and prone to verification errors, would this example work, and how to I do simple checks in the member initialisation? From what I understand the member initialisation list can do logical if statements ( X ? A : B ), though I cannot fathom how I would verify input.

EDIT: I have a default ctor and overloaded for MONITORINFOEX

```
SingleMonitorInfo::SingleMonitorInfo()
:dMaxPercentDifference(1), // Double
iCheckTaskbar(1), // int
rcMonitorArea(RECT{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }), // RECT
rcWorkArea(RECT{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }), // RECT
dwStatusFlags(DWORD(0x00000000)), // DWORD
dwCapabilitiesFlags(DWORD(0x00000000)), // DWORD
szDeviceName({ '\0' }), // String (WCHAR)
szMonitorName({ '\0' }), // String (WCHAR)
szMonitorDescription({ '\0' }), // String (WCHAR)
lpPixelArray(NULL) // unsigned char*
```

{

}

Comment: well, that is a member initialization list, hard to comment on its correctness without seeing more of the relevant code though.  For the entries with `({'\0'})` that is somewhat unconventional; you could use `{}` instead here, or even inline in the class definition.    The magic number `33` is a red flag, this should probably be some sort of `sizeof` expression

Comment: I am unsure of what more relevant code is needed. As to the size of the WCHAR(s) I do know the max size from winAPI (32, and 128) so I just assumed this was okay.

Comment: what do you mean 'from winAPI'? `szDeviceName`  is, presumably, an array member of this class you wrote yourself. Maybe the class definition contains `wchar_t szDeviceName[16];` , the readers don't know.  Maybe later in time you will change the length of this array in the class definition and forget to change the constructor.  Using the right length based on the array avoids the possibility of these two getting out of sync, and makes it easier for someone reading the code to know that it works correctly.

Comment: @M.M - Sorry, I meant from MSDN. I understand and I will change it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be necessary to perform checks in your member initializer list, and if you need to perform checks, you probably need to rethink your design.

Let's look at your class:

```
SingleMonitorInfo::SingleMonitorInfo(MONITORINFOEX* lpMONITORINFOEX)
:rcMonitorArea(lpMONITORINFOEX->rcMonitor),
rcWorkArea(lpMONITORINFOEX->rcWork),
dwStatusFlags(lpMONITORINFOEX->dwFlags),
szDeviceName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorDescription({ '\0' }),
lpPixelArray(NULL)
```

Here we can see a pretty big problem if `lpMONITORINFOEX` is `nullptr`. It looks like your class **needs** it to function though. Ask yourself: could I have a `SingleMonitorInfo` class without a `MONITORINFOEX` object?

If your class **needs** that object, make it more explicit by passing a reference!

```
SingleMonitorInfo::SingleMonitorInfo(const MONITORINFOEX& lpMONITORINFOEX)
:rcMonitorArea(lpMONITORINFOEX.rcMonitor),
rcWorkArea(lpMONITORINFOEX.rcWork),
dwStatusFlags(lpMONITORINFOEX.dwFlags),
szDeviceName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorDescription({ '\0' }),
lpPixelArray(NULL)
```

Users of your class can no longer construct your object incorrectly. If for some reason `lpMONITORINFOEX` was optional, and needed to remain a pointer, you could simply use the ternary operator `?:`

```
SingleMonitorInfo::SingleMonitorInfo(MONITORINFOEX* lpMONITORINFOEX)
:rcMonitorArea(lpMONITORINFOEX ? lpMONITORINFOEX->rcMonitor : nullptr),
rcWorkArea(lpMONITORINFOEX ? lpMONITORINFOEX->rcWork : false),
dwStatusFlags(lpMONITORINFOEX ? lpMONITORINFOEX->dwFlags : 0),
szDeviceName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorName({ '\0' }),
szMonitorDescription({ '\0' }),
lpPixelArray(NULL)
```

<sub>Obviously I don't know what your objects are, so I'm just guessing default input.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your observations, I have changed it to const and passed a reference. This is why I wanted to check the input but there is no need with what you described. Very helpful.