# Join two different object vectors<t> by variable(s)

Tags: c++, vector

I am unsure of how to merge two vectors.

```
std::vector<MONITORINFOEX> newList
std::vector<SingleMonitorInfo> oldList
```

It needs to compare `newList[i].szMonitor (WCHAR[32])` against `oldList[j].szMonitor (WCHAR[32])`, as well as work out the respect resolutions of each `newList[i].rcMonitor (RECT)` against `oldList[j].rcMonitor (RECT)`

Where:

- i is all monitors in new list
- j is all monitors in old list

Then concatenate, join, merge the list into one (If they are the same szMonitor and resolution) then it just needs to update the two RECT variables inside newList to oldList: Whilst removing any object (monitor) in oldList that is not in newList and adding any object that is in newList but not in oldList.

Comment: There isn't a way for those two objects to be in the same container, unless  one inherits the other or they both inherit the same class; however, if these classes are the same as the ones in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35401261/is-this-ctor-use-of-ctor-correct), it's possible to create a `SingleMonitorInfo` from a `MonitorInfoEx`

Comment: @Tas Yes, they are same classes. I can oldList.push_back(SingleMonitorInfo(MonitorInfoEx)). Do I have to code it the same as I would with an array opposed to using vectors?